# C#: How to declare a checked switch-expression-bodied function?

Tags: c#, exception, switch-statement, checked, expression-body

I'm stuyding C# (10.0/.NET6) and I've got a question.
There is a code:

```csharp
Int32 x = Int32.MaxValue;
Int32 y = Int32.MaxValue;

try
{
  WriteLine($"{x} * {y} = {SomeFuncSwitch(x, y, 2)}");
  WriteLine($"{x} + {y} = {SomeFunc(x, y)}");
}
catch ( OverflowException ex )
{
  WriteLine( $"Overflow in {ex.TargetSite}!" );
}

static Int32 SomeFunc(Int32 x, Int32 y) => checked (x + y);

static Int32 SomeFuncSwitch(Int32 x, Int32 y, UInt16 condition) =>
checked (
  condition switch
  {
    1 => x + y,
    _ => x * y
  }
);
```

`SomeFunc()` throws exception, whereas `SomeFuncSwitch()` does not. It will if **every** switch case is `checked`. Is there a (proper) way to use single `checked`?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me, I would advise you to post this on the proper Github page as an issue and see what the response is. I am not entirely sure what the right project is though.

Comment: Created a [github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/61843) issue (though possibly should be runtime, not compiler). Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a consequence of the use of a `checked` expression with a switch expression.

If you do it like this (via a `checked` block), it works as expected:

```
static Int32 SomeFuncSwitch(Int32 x, Int32 y, UInt16 condition)
{
    checked
    {
        return condition switch
        {
            1 => x + y,
            _ => x * y
        };
    }
}
```

Like you, I would have expected the original code to work. Possibly there is some bug in the way the code is generated.

It certainly looks like a compiler bug. If you look at [the decompiled C# code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYAGAWACgiBGCi/KpAAiOaoHYKBvCx31p/CkYBZAIYBLAHYAKAJQ8+3cnxWMAkpIAuAZkKMEjALzqtugHRiEANVEAbAK4wA3AtUmdegJ5H35yzYdnWmU3RgBlCABbGHwAVjCAd3FNMAALaQQ0Rk8swlkXEN4AX2CVeiYND3ComNjpSt19LIavWSMAPkY0mDAAaxgMDMZsbPzSvnLfPQjouMTktPrTPUyp7KyAVUqGLohJDGTxPflCxiVQ5jYu1J7+wdcL3f3DvcYAZySU1IeL88e3KgdfTDdY/f6MAD6QIMACpsmC3CVTioxqckUUgA=) you can see that the `checked` expression is missing from `SomeFuncSwitch()` but it is not missing from `SomeFunc()`.

Comment: @MatthewWhatson, thanks. I wonder if it is possible with a `=> switch` syntax

Comment: @OldSkull I don't think that's possible because the syntax doesn't allow it.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I use `1 => checked(x+y)` and similar for multiplication, the decompiled c# 1.0 version in LINQPad puts the checked operator outside of the switch, this looks more and more like a conflict between multiple code rewriters.

Comment: Created a [github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/61843) issue. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @GuruStron, it seems there'll be some duplicates :)

Comment: As long as we've agreed this is a bug, should I accept this answer?